# Adding a duplicate InstallShield prerequisite with a different condition

Tags: installshield, prerequisites

I am using InstallShield Spring 2012. Currently, my company uses a VC redistributable prerequisite for their installer. The way the condition was set up originally, did not cover all of our users issues and so it had to be changed. Since InstallShield handles prerequisite conditions with AND operators, I had a rough time because I needed to point to different registry keys on x64 and x86. This forced me to create 2 prerequisites for the same VC redistributable. Upon doing so, I ran into a new problem where the VC redist file was being duplicated in our installer, thus increasing the size of the installer by 4.3MB. To fix the size issue, I gave both prerequisites the same GUID. This does work, although I am now getting an error upon building.

The error I am seeing is (GUID and file paths below are not actual ones in use):
ISDEV : error -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\vc9\vcredist_x86_vc9sp1.exe' to target 'C:\MyApplication\temp\ISSetupPrerequisites{L4530M2D-G0U7-9437-326H-14
PDGA5R257T}\vcredist_x86_vc9sp1.exe'

Even with the error, everything seems to work fine. My guess is that InstallShield is placing the VC redist under that GUID folder and when it wants to copy it again to that same location for the second prereq, it is running into a problem, which possibly might be due to read only or folder already being in use.

Is there some way around this so that I do not get this error upon building? If someone knows of a better approach to any of the issues I faced in this post, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067525/which-vc-redistributable-package-to-choose-x86-or-x64

Comment: My company's software is only x86 right now and only uses the x86 redist. When installing to a x64 OS, I have to take into account the location in the registry where the software's entry is placed (SOFTWARE or SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node). This is what forced me to create 2 prerequisites for the same vc redist due to having 2 separate conditions based on OS architecture.

Comment: I'd have to look at it... that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Could you clarify which registry keys you are needing to look at differently depending on the OS? If your code is always 32-bit, you will always need the 32-bit redist, and it should always put down the same registry key (modulo 64-bit registry redirections).

Comment: I may have been working too hard on this and got confused. After glancing at it again, I think what you are saying will work Michael. I did however find a workaround until I can get back to this issue. The workaround involves making a C# windows forms app that I have hidden which calls the redist from the parent directory that contains the redist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely was overlooking this. I did not have to have separate prereqs for x86 and x64. To fix this, I just had it point to x86 paths, no matter what OS was being used. This solved the issue. THanks Michael.